# How to pass variables to the routing file using laravel / lumen?

Tags: laravel, lumen, anonymous-function

At the bottom of bootstrap/app.php there's the following code to include the routes file...

```
$app->router->group([
  'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});
```

$router is now available within the required web.php file, which makes sense, however I don't see how or where $router was created to be passed in to the anonymous function... hope that makes sense... thanks to any responders.

Comment: Interesting approach! What exact problems are you having with this? Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5128173/4672917), I believe this is ok.

Comment: As for how it was created and passed, you can see `Illuminate\Routing\Router` lines 367, 374, and 414. If the 2nd parameter is a closure, it is invoked with instance of itself is passed as a parameter

Comment: @Julio Motol, thanks for the response, it's the approach that comes with a default install of Lumen 7. There doesn't appear to be  a Vendor\Illuminate\Routing\Router. The script works fine, I'm just trying to understand why?.. as at the point of being passed to the anonymous function $router has not been set, yet within the required file $router appears to be an instance of Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router.

Comment: I was looking at this in Laravel. I checked the source code for Lumen and saw the [router script](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/7.x/src/Routing/Router.php#L54) it works just the same as Laravel. The `Router` invokes the anonymous function with an instance of itself as a parameter hence the `$router` in the anonymous function.

Comment: @JulioMotol, I was reading the code as though you were running the function at the point it is written, therefore $router would need to be set, but in fact it is the blueprint of a function, that doesn’t get run until you run the $app->router->group method.
Which as you pointed out, is where it passes an instance of the $app->router object to set the $router variable in the anonymous function.
Does that sound about right?.. please add your comment above as an answer and I will mark it correct, many thanks, J :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code for the [Router class](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/7.x/src/Routing/Router.php#L54), the Router invokes the anonymous function with an instance of itself as a parameter hence the $router in the anonymous function.